# Jenkins does not run .exe in python script

Tags: python, jenkins

Hello and thanks for your help!

I have the following test.py:

```
import subprocess, sys


print("starting calc.exe")
subprocess.call(["calc.exe"])
print("started calculator")
```

The current status is: If we run the test.py on the cmd, it works perfectly. But if we run the same test.py within Jenkins, nothing happens. Also, there isn´t an error message, the test.py runs continuously and the task is successfully completed.

Furthermore, Jenkins is running on Windows users with no admin rights. Could that be a possible problem? Checked this with temporary admin rights, but delivered the same result. Or is it possible that there are any other restrictions that deny a job called in Jenkins to run other extern files (for example .exe)?

Console Output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Python Test>C:\Users\XXXXX\.conda\envs\RegTestEnv\python.exe test.py 

starting calc.exe

started calculator

C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\Python Test>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Maybe this makes sense: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21409578/1084416

Comment: You can check the permission to execute both test.py and calc.exe. May be the jenkins user has not correct permission to execute,

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission to execute both test.py and calc.exe. May be the jenkins user has not permission to execute

Answer (score -1):

Have you changed it?
Go to Regedit

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

and set "EnableLUA"= 0